# Craft.createElementSelectorModal in a tooltip is causing field to disappear

Tags: plugin-development

**Problem:**

In a plugin for a custom field I want to have an Element Selection Modal so I'm calling: `Craft.createElementSelectorModal()`

On an Element Detail page this is no problem. But, in a tooltip (say from the element Index for example) calling the same code causes the Field to be completely removed from the DOM.

I've even tried this with no settings:

`Craft.createElementSelectorModal('Entry', {})`

And it's still the same thing, the entire field gets removed from the DOM just on initialization.

**Questions:**

Is `Craft.createElementSelectorModal` still the right thing to use to trigger an Element Selection modal?

If not, is there something else I should use?

**Image Progression:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit:
For what it's worth I also tried `BaseElementSelectInput` and had the exact same results.